# Capturing groups with condition on existence

Tags: javascript, regex, web

I have url like

```
http://localhost:8080/web/group/555/content/777/image?arg1=1&arg2=2#anchor
```

There are 3 parts i'm trying to get: **group number**, **content number** and the **view type** value which is "image" in the sample above (can be one of predefined set of values and it is guarateed no values with text "group" or "content").

I got following regexp so far (it has 3 capturing groups i need)

```
/.*(?:\/group\/([\d]+))(?:\/content\/([\d]+))\/([\w]+).*/g
```

which works only when all the parts are present.

The problem is any of the part can be absent (except "view type"), so next urls are also valid:

```
http://localhost:8080/web/content/777/image
// which has $1="", $2="777", $3="image"
http://localhost:8080/web/nogroup/555/content/777/video
// which has $1="", $2="777", $3="video"
http://localhost:8080/web/audio
// which has $1="", $2="", $3="audio"
```

Is there a way to tell regexp: if there is no matching for the group $1 set its value to ""?

Comment: If you add a question mark (`?`) after each of the groups that may be present but aren't necessary, it should automatically populate them with `""` if they don't exist.

Comment: I've posted that as an answer so that you can officially accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a question mark `?` after each of the groups that can be present but aren't necessary for a match and it will automatically populate them with `""`:

```
/.*(?:\/group\/([\d]+))?(?:\/content\/([\d]+))?\/([\w]+).*/g
```